# Base64 SHA-512 hash not working as intended

Tags: hash, base64, sha512

Hello I'm trying to get the Base64 encoded value of a SHA512 hash. I want my output to match the output using this [site](https://hash.online-convert.com/sha512-generator) but I can't seem to get it when I try step by step. For example,

The string `admin` gives `x61Ey612Kl2gpFL56FT9weDnpSo4AV8j8+qx2AuTHdRyY036xxzTTrw10Wq3+4qQyB+XURPWx1ONxp3Y3pB37A==` when I use the site above.

When I try it step by step, I use a SHA-512 hash generator on `admin` which results in `C7AD44CBAD762A5DA0A452F9E854FDC1E0E7A52A38015F23F3EAB1D80B931DD472634DFAC71CD34EBC35D16AB7FB8A90C81F975113D6C7538DC69DD8DE9077EC`

and then I use a Base64 encoder on that which gives me `QzdBRDQ0Q0JBRDc2MkE1REEwQTQ1MkY5RTg1NEZEQzFFMEU3QTUyQTM4MDE1RjIzRjNFQUIxRDgwQjkzMURENDcyNjM0REZBQzcxQ0QzNEVCQzM1RDE2QUI3RkI4QTkwQzgxRjk3NTExM0Q2Qzc1MzhEQzY5REQ4REU5MDc3RUM=`

which is different. How do I obtain the first output above?

Comment: What language and environment are you using?  Can you show your code that produces that hash?

Comment: As of now I'm literally just using https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha512-hash-generator/ to generate the SHA-512 hash then https://www.base64encode.org/ to encode it to Base64

Comment: The sites doesn't work. It looks like a spam or advertising of this site. This post should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two different transformations in play here: the SHA-512 hash of an input and the Base64 encoding of an input.  They can be combined or used alone.

`C7AD44CBAD762A5DA0A452F9E854FDC1E0E7A52A38015F23F3EAB1D80B931DD472634DFAC71CD34EBC35D16AB7FB8A90C81F975113D6C7538DC69DD8DE9077EC` is the SHA-512 hash of the text `admin` represented in uppercase hexadecimal.

`QzdBRDQ0Q0JBRDc2MkE1REEwQTQ1MkY5RTg1NEZEQzFFMEU3QTUyQTM4MDE1RjIzRjNFQUIxRDgwQjkzMURENDcyNjM0REZBQzcxQ0QzNEVCQzM1RDE2QUI3RkI4QTkwQzgxRjk3NTExM0Q2Qzc1MzhEQzY5REQ4REU5MDc3RUM=`  is the SHA-512 hash of the text `admin` represented in uppercase hexadecimal and then encoded with Base64.

`x61Ey612Kl2gpFL56FT9weDnpSo4AV8j8+qx2AuTHdRyY036xxzTTrw10Wq3+4qQyB+XURPWx1ONxp3Y3pB37A==` is the SHA-512 hash of the text `admin` in encoded with Base64.  There was no intermediate transformation to hexadecimal.

In other words, `x61Ey612Kl2gpFL56FT9weDnpSo4AV8j8+qx2AuTHdRyY036xxzTTrw10Wq3+4qQyB+XURPWx1ONxp3Y3pB37A==` is the Base64 encoding of the hash output *bytes*, and `QzdBRDQ0Q0JBRDc2MkE1REEwQTQ1MkY5RTg1NEZEQzFFMEU3QTUyQTM4MDE1RjIzRjNFQUIxRDgwQjkzMURENDcyNjM0REZBQzcxQ0QzNEVCQzM1RDE2QUI3RkI4QTkwQzgxRjk3NTExM0Q2Qzc1MzhEQzY5REQ4REU5MDc3RUM=` is the Base64 encoding of the hash output *text* (in uppercase hexadecimal).

Comment: How to get this base64 encoded hash without the hexadecimal conversion through terminal?

Comment: @Heich-B If I understand you, you're looking to go from input → hash bytes → base64?  That would be a separate question, if it hasn't been asked already, either on here, [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), or possibly [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (depending on what you mean by "terminal").

Comment: Ohh okay. I just posted on "Unix and Linux" Exchange platform. Thank you.